# Post data-attribute with php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, custom-data-attribute

I'm having troubles with posting the value of a data attrubute e.g. data-fruit="orange" I basically want to do it with jQuery ajax and I imagine it would look something like this

```
var fruit = $(".fruit img").attr("data-skin");

$('.box').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'fruits.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: fruit
  });
});
```

Should the php $_POST look like this:

```
$friutType = $_POST['data-friut']
```

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to send key/value pairs to `data`, not just a value.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'fruits.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {fruit: fruit}
});
```

Then in PHP:

```
$friutType = $_POST['fruit']
```

Comment: should be $fruitType = $_POST['fruit']

Comment: @MarkK: Thanks.  I can't spell =/